# PHP object get value from array

Tags: php, object

I have written a class like this:-

```
class Mail{
    function register()
    {
    return array('message_subject'=>$message_subject,'message_content'=>$message_content);
    }
}
```

Then in the main page, I tried:-

```
echo Mail::register();
```

and the main page gave me values of "Array".

how shall I modify the Mail::register(); so that it can receive "message_subject" and "message_content" respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign the Mail::register() into a variable and then print it because you are retruning an array from that. Array is always printed by print_f not by echo

```
$mail = Mail::register();
echo'<pre>';
print_r($mail);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

with parameters

```
class Mail{
    function register($message_subject, $message_content)
    {
        return array('message_subject'=>$message_subject,'message_content'=>$message_content);
    }
}

echo Mail::register('foo', 'bar')
```

or with member fields

```
class Mail {
  private $message_subject;
  private $message_content;

  public function __construct($subject, $content) {
    $this->message_subject = $subject;
    $this->message_content = $content;
  }

  function register() {
    return array('message_subject' => $this->message_subject,'message_content' => $this->message_content);
  }
}

$mail = new Mail('foo', 'bar');
$mail->register();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$mail = new Mail();
list($subject, $content) = $mail->register();
```

Or

```
$mail = new Mail();
$data = $mail->register();
printf("%s \n %s", $data['message_subject'], $data['message_content']);
```

and my guess is that your class is like this :

```
class Mail {
    private $subject, $content;

    function __construct() {
        $this->subject = "Demo";
        $this->content = "Hello World";
    }

    function register() {
        return array(
                'message_subject' => $this->subject,
                'message_content' => $this->content
        );
    }
}
```